# What's the best way to compute row-wise (or axis-wise) dot products with jax?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, jax

I have two numerical arrays of shape (N, M). I'd like to compute a row-wise dot product. I.e. produce an array of shape (N,) such that the nth row is the dot product of the nth row from each array.

I'm aware of numpy's `inner1d` method. What would the best way be to do this with jax? jax has `jax.numpy.inner`, but this does something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own jit-compiled version of `inner1d` in a few lines of jax code:

```
import jax
@jax.jit
def inner1d(X, Y):
  return (X * Y).sum(-1)
```

Testing it out:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np
from numpy.core import umath_tests


X = np.random.rand(5, 10)
Y = np.random.rand(5, 10)

print(umath_tests.inner1d(X, Y))
print(inner1d(jnp.array(X), jnp.array(Y)))
# [2.23219571 2.1013316  2.70353783 2.14094973 2.62582531]
# [2.2321959 2.1013315 2.703538  2.1409497 2.6258256]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [jax.numpy.einsum](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.einsum.html). Here the implementaion using numpy einsum

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

arr1 = np.random.randint(0,10,[5,5])
arr2 = np.random.randint(0,10,[5,5])

arr = np.inner1d(arr1,arr2)
arr
array([ 87, 200, 229,  81,  53])
np.einsum('...i,...i->...',arr1,arr2)
array([ 87, 200, 229,  81,  53])
```